# Swift - How to ask UIGestureRecognizer function to return value

Tags: swift, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to ask function annotation to return the coordinate (CLLocationCoordinate2D) for other function to use, here's my partial code:

```
// ULMap is MapView. 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    var longPressGR = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "annotation:")
    longPressGR.minimumPressDuration = 1
    UImap.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGR)
}

func annotation(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){

    //Coordinate
    var touchPoint = gesture.locationInView(self.UImap)
    var coordinate = UImap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.UImap)

}
```

I tried this one, but it doesn't work:

```
func annotation(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D{

    //Coordinate
    var touchPoint = gesture.locationInView(self.UImap)
    var coordinate = UImap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.UImap)

    return coordinate
}
```

Is there a way to do this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like gesture recognizer calls can't return anything because you aren't the one who is calling them. They are getting called by the system, so any return value will propagate back up through code you don't have access to. You should create a class level variable for your coordinate and set that.

so instead of saying
    var coordinate = UImap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.UImap)

you declare

```
var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

at class scope, and then in your function

```
coordinate = UImap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.UImap)
```

Then coordinate will always be the most recently set coordinate. You can add them to an array if you need to keep track of more than one.

Comment: Good job deciphering what the OP was asking.